# Nested Jquery Calls

Tags: jquery

Today I came across this in some code:

```
$($($(this).children()[1])).css("border-color", "#fff");
```

I haven't seen this before, and to the best of my understanding, writing the following will accomplish the same thing:

```
$(this).children()[1].css("border-color", "#fff");
```

Is there any purpose to the top way (is it better?), or is this just someone now knowing what they are doing with JQuery?

Comment: I see no reason for doing that. Maybe they originally had other stuff between the parentheses, but decided to remove that stuff... only to forget the parens... makes no sense otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second expression won't do the same thing, because accessing array elements of a jQuery collection returns the DOM node, not a jQuery object, and you can't call jQuery methods on it. The actual equivalent would be:

```
$(this).children().eq(1).css("border-color", "#fff");
```

The first code is equivalent to:

```
var temp = $(this).children()[1]; // Get DOM node of 2nd child
$(temp).css("border-color", "#fff"); // Wrap it in jQuery object and set CSS
```

Comment: @Zenith The first works because the subscripted expression returns a DOM node, and `jQuery(node)` wraps that node in a jQuery object.

Comment: Doesn't the first one still have an extra `$` ?

Comment: @Johannes ya, one wrapping is useless

Comment: @Barmar Ah :) I have only really seen it inside one "set" before (e.g. `$($())` ), but didn't know if more outer objects than that would have any effect.

Comment: I didn't notice the extra level of wrapping. `$(<jquery-object>)` is a no-op, it just returns the object.

Comment: In any case, calling `$($(something)[0])` will always be slower than `$(something).eq(0)`, right?

Answer (score 2):

The only reason in the first example it's that [0] returns from the array the '0' indexed element out of the jQuery objects array (AKA: collection).

```
$('p')[0].hide(); // will NOT work
```

(`[0]` is the JS *getter* from array, something like `.get()` method in jQuery)

that's why it's wrapped again inside a jQuery object function

```
$( $('p')[0] ).hide();  // Hides the '0' <p> element
```

You can also wrap jQ objects into additional objects*

```
$( $( $( $( $('p') ) ) ) ).hide();
```

*which is unneded, redundand , slow, **Wrong** in any case

**Resume:**

```
$( $('p')[0] ).hide();     // WORKS! cause the JS HTMLelement is
                           // again wrapped into an jQ Object

$( $('p').get(0) ).hide(); // WORKS (same reason)

$('p')[0].hide();          // WRONG! returns the unoperable (by jQ) JS Object
                           // HTMLelement, not a jQuery object

$('p').get(0).hide();      // WRONG! (same reason)

$( $( $( $( $('p')[0] ) ) ) ).hide();       // WTH?!
```

**Playground: http://jsbin.com/enawup/3/edit**

Comment: Thanks for the additional info the the array stuff, definitely helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Those will both do the same thing, just the 1st option is much slower.

Same as:

```
$(this).children().eq(1).css("border-color", "#fff");
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not better. If anything - it's less efficient. Use `.eq(1)` in your code to make it work.

Even better (most efficient):

```
$(this).children()[1].style.borderColor = '#fff';
```

Answer (score 1):

i doubt your code works.... since `.css` is a jquery method and `$(this).children()[1]` returns DOM element which will have no method call `.css()`..

**the first method is slower and messy..however it works since it is wrapping the DOM element with `$()` to use it as jquery object.. and i am sure one extra(outer) $() in first example is not needed at all.**

```
$($(this).children()[1]).css("border-color", "#fff"); //this should work
```

you can get the result by using `first()`

```
 $('div').children().first().css("color", "red");
```

or `eq()`

```
 $(this).children().eq(1).css("border-color", "#fff");
```